# How to specify recognition region in ABBYY OCR library?

Tags: android, image-processing, sdk, ocr, abbyy

I am using abbyy ocr mobile sdk for android application development. 
I want to detect text in specific region.
Can anyone help me to specify recognition area in abbyy mobile sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, how it is done on android, but this may help even if i am using iOS. There are build phases which copy `keywords`, `dictionaries` and `patterns`. The pre-selected settings are set onto the english dictionary/keywords. So you might take a look at your project file and seek for `English.akw` or `English.edc` and replace this entries with the desired region.

Also, you might search for `ocrConfiguration` in the code. This contains recognition languages.

Comment: Hello @Tobias , Please help me, I want to detection only the number. I have search English.edc in my code. I get this file. but this is not open in mac. Please help me how can I change this file only for number detection. In IOS

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do it on Android sdk, but Abbyy sdk is similar in every language. I'll give you and c# example and I hope you'll find it usefull.

You have two options:

- You can create a layout with blocks:

  ```
  FRDocument document = engine.CreateFRDocument();
  Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
  rectangle.X = 160; 
  rectangle.Y = 42; 
  rectangle.Width = 240; 
  rectangle.Height = 37;
  CrearBloque(rectangle, "BlockName");

  private void CrearBloque(Rectangle rectangle, string name)
  {
       FREngine.Region region = engineLoader.Engine.CreateRegion();
       region.AddRect(
            rectangle.Left, 
            rectangle.Top, 
            rectangle.Width + rectangle.Left, 
            rectangle.Height + rectangle.Top);

       ITextBlock block = document.Pages[0].Layout.Blocks.AddNew(
            BlockTypeEnum.BT_Text, region, -1).GetAsTextBlock();

       block.Name = name;
  }

  //And finally you can save your your document's layout:
  document.Pages[0].Layout.SaveToFile("path_of_the_layout");
  ```
- You can also load a layout file with blocks saved:

  ```
  document.Pages[0].Layout.LoadFromFile("path_of_the_layout");
  ```

**VERY IMPORTANT!!!**

Don't forget to use `document.recognize()` method.

Never use `document.Process()`.